# How to get background color on mouse hover of inactive tab in jquery ui using jquery css framework?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav  li>A:hover {
    
    background-color:#e7e7e7 !important;

}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li:hover {
background-color:#e7e7e7 !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="tabs" style="border: 1px solid #ffffff; visibility: hidden;"> 
    <ul style="background-color: White; border: 1px solid #ffffff; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC; background-image: none;"> 
        <li id="liTab1" style="background-color: White;">
            <a href="#tabs1" id="alTab1">abc</a> 
            <span id="spnTab1" class='ui-icon'></span> 
        </li> 
        <li id="liTab2" style="background-color: White;">
            <a href="#tabs2" id="alTab2" >r</a>
            <span id="spnTab2" class='ui-icon'></span>
        </li> 
    </ul>
```

How to fix the hover on mouse hover?

Comment: Please show complete code which we could test

Comment: What is your html?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend new users review [ask] for tips on how to form questions that best enable the community to assist you.  This question will require more details to get truly useful answers; can you provide an [mcve] of code in the question?

Comment: <div id="tabs" style="border: 1px solid #ffffff; visibility: hidden;"> <ul style="background-color: White; border: 1px solid #ffffff; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC; background-image: none;"> <li id="liTab1" style="background-color: White;"><a href="#tabs1" id="alTab1">abc</a> <span id="spnTab1" class='ui-icon'></span> </li> <li id="liTab2" style="background-color: White;"><a href="#tabs2" id="alTab2" >r</a><span id="spnTab2" class='ui-icon'></span></li> </ul>

Comment: @EzhumalaiS  unable to found these classes : `ui-tabs , ui-tabs-nav` in your given HTML code. As well as what you want to fix which is already hidden? `<div id="tabs" style="border: 1px solid #ffffff; visibility: hidden;"> `-> since it's not visible on browser, what you are trying to fix?